# Is it safe to cast to int from std::round?

Tags: c++, floating-point, rounding

I have a question about [std::round](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/) with signature: `double round (double x);`

Let's say I have this code:

```
int i = std::round(0.9);
```

In this case, `std::round` should return `1.00000000000`, but that's uncomfortably close to `0.9999999999999` and I'm concerned that floating-point errors will end up rounding this down.

I would hope that `i == 1`, but is this guaranteed?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/rint

Comment: @Mat as far as I can see the only difference is `round` explicitly does not respect the current rounding mode. The guarantees are otherwise the same.

Comment: @BoBTFish: the `lrint` variants return integral values, not integral values in floating point format. Not quite the same (as far as I understand it)

Comment: Worth mentioning that double can store much larger numbers than int and signed integet overflow is UB (not arbitrary or IB, real UB - I've seen e.g. infinite loops from signed int overflow).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `std::round` function returns a floating point value, "*rounding halfway cases away from zero*". As with any `double` to `int` implicit conversion the compiler will issue a warning:

> conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data

Use [std::lround](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) or [std::lrint](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/rint) if you want to return an integral value.

Comment: `rint` seems to have exactly the same guarantees as `round`, other than respecting the currently set rounding mode.

Comment: @BoBTFish I have updated the answer with the `std::lrint` variant.

Comment: This does not explicitly answer the question (and neither do the other answers). Floating-point errors do not happen randomly or arbitrarily; a value of exactly 1 returned by `std::round` is not going to be arbitrarily changed into something else. Technically, the C and C++ standards fail to provide guarantees about various aspects of floating-point behavior, but no normal implementation would have any error in converting the (mathematical) integer result of `std::round` to an `int` as long as the result is within range of an `int`.

Comment: (I am not saying the OP should not be advised to use `std::lround` or `std::lrint` in this case, just pointing out that we have not actually answered the explicit question and explained how floating-point works.)

Answer (score 9):

Yes. So long as you don't overflow the receiving type.

You have no concerns here: `std::round(0.9)` will round to *exactly* `1.0` and so `i == 1` **is guaranteed**

The standard insists on the *closest* integral value assumable by a `double` being returned.

Note though that for an IEEE754 `double`, all values over the 52nd power of 2 are integral values! A corollary of that is that your candidate number for rounding is *already* an integral value, so the function reduces to a no-op. So the fact, for example, that `std::round(4503599627370496.5)` will return `4503599627370496` is all to do with the fact that `4503599627370496.5` cannot be represented as a `double` in the first place.

As final technical point, note that `std::round` is remarkably well-behaved, due in part to the fact that any number of the form `a.5` (which is the cutover point in rounding) is a *dyadic rational* and so can be represented exactly in binary floating point. This is why an alternative approach, such as adding `0.5` and truncating, can introduce bugs since joke digits can be introduced if you do that.

Answer (score 5):

The C++ Standard defers to the C Standard for this. In N1570 (~C11), the description of `round` is as follows:

> The `round` functions round their argument to the nearest integer value in floating-point format, rounding halfway cases away from zero, regardless of the current rounding direction.

However, as Ron pointed out, functions such as `lrint` do exactly what you want.

Comment: "Note that this may not be the nearest integer" That's wrong. It will be. If the number is not integer, then both integers around it is available. If it is integer, then there is nothing to do.

Comment: @geza Absolutely correct, of course. Removed that part.

Answer (score 1):

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

**Floating–integral conversions**

> **A prvalue of floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of any
>   integer type. The fractional part is truncated, that is, the
>   fractional part is discarded. If the value cannot fit into the
>   destination type, the behavior is undefined** (even when the destination
>   type is unsigned, modulo arithmetic does not apply). If the
>   destination type is bool, this is a boolean conversion (see below).

Comment: The question seems to be, is it safe to use `round` then follow with this truncation? I.e. is `round` guaranteed to return something such that the result of the truncation give mathematically the same value?

Answer (score 1):

Although this isn't a proof that it will be true on all platforms, you can just try to round all possible floating point values and see what happens:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
  // Define the range of valid 'int' values
  const float mi = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
  const float ma = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

  float maxd = -std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
  std::size_t k = 0;
  // Iterate over all float point values between 'mi' and 'ma'
  for (float f = mi; f < ma; f = std::nextafter(f, ma), ++k) {
    // Static cast after round
    auto i = static_cast<int>(std::round(f));
    // Convert back to float and check the difference
    float d = std::abs(static_cast<float>(i) - f);
    // Store the largest recorded difference
    if (d > maxd) {
      maxd = d;
    }
    // Print progress to the console, just to see it's not stuck
    if (k % 1321 == 0) {
      std::cout << k << ": " << f << "               \r";
    }
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  // Prints 0.5 for me
  std::cout << maxd << std::endl;
}
```

If what you feared could happen did happen, the program above would print a value larger than 0.5.

Answer (score -2):

how about adding 0.5 and then casting to int (truncating)

```
if(x < 0) { //number is negative
 return (int) x - 0.5;
} else {
 return (int) x + 0.5;//number is positive
}
```

in your example it should return 1 for sure 
  because 1.49999999999 cast to int is 1

Comment: Very very naughty; this approach fails on some edge cases. Java had this bug up to 1.5. Plus you've messed up your operator precedence; you are casting to an `int`, **then** adding the constant!